# Range parameter on the MDX-query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a correct MDX-query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Projects].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [Reports]
WHERE [CreatedOn].[Date].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00]:[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2010-02-01T00:00:00]
```

I need to create SSRS-report with filter on CreatedOn dimension.

Here is my non-working solution:

- I transform query to:

  ```
  SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY { ([Projects].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
  FROM (SELECT (STRTOSET(@CreatedOnDate, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Reports])
  ```
- CreatedOnDate parameter (type = datetime)
- Set value of CreatedOnDate parameter to value:

  ```
  ="[CreatedOn].[Date].[" + Format(CDate(Parameters!CreatedOnDate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]"
  ```

But when I run the report I get:

```
The restriction imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the parameter is not what you think. CONSTRAINED flag will force generating an error if the string is not a member when using [StrToSet MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/StrToSet.html) (check the failing example) :

You can try without the CONSTRAINED flag or find out the value of your parameter :

```
WITH 
 MEMBER myParam AS "[CreatedOn].[Date].[" + 
                   Format(CDate(Parameters!CreatedOnDate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd") 
                   + "T00:00:00]"
SELECT
  [Measures].[myParam] on 0
FORM [Reports]
```

Playing a bit with this should make easier spotting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use STRTOMEMBER for each side of the range

```
STRTOMEMBER("[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00]", constrained):STRTOMEMBER("[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2010-02-01T00:00:00]", constrained)
```