# Implementing a date range in SSRS with the data coming from a cube

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have been trying to implement a date range parameter in SSRS 2015. The data is from a cube. I dragged my date into the dimension box of the query designer and went into the parameter tab to change the fromDate and toDate to date/time format and this resulted in the following MDX query.

```
SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDate, CONSTRAINED) : 
STRTOMEMBER(@ToDate, CONSTRAINED) )
```

My date format is dd/mm/yyyy. I have looked on several forums and tried a few method but continued to get the error:

```
The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOMEMBER function 
were violated
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters will need to be formed in full address `mdx`. e.g. @FromDate could be this - I've used the DateKey:

```
'[Date Dim].[Date Hier].&[20180301]'
```

So some concatenation, within ssrs, would be required before getting passed:

```
"[Date Dim].[Date Hier].&[" + 20180301 + "]"  //<<you'll need to change to the names used in your cube
```

I'd also be tempted to use `strToSet` as you want a set. So mine might be something like:

```
( STRTOSET( "[Date Dim].[Date Hier].&[" + @FromDate + "]:" +
          "[Date Dim].[Date Hier].&[" + @ToDate + "]" , CONSTRAINED) )
```

Here is a good reference: [Range parameter on the MDX-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503980/range-parameter-on-the-mdx-query#8506268)

Comment: Thank you, Ill have a look into this now and give it a test

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received means that the parameter values do not exist in the cube in that format. To solve this you need to create a field that can be formatted and displayed to users without changing the value that the query uses.

When you create parameters in the Query Designer, it automatically creates hidden datasets which populate the Available Values for the parameter. To see this, right-click on the Datasets folder and select Show Hidden Datasets.

Now, go to the dataset properties and add a calculated field in the Fields tab. This will be your nicely formatted date.

In the parameter properties for each parameter, go to the Available Values tab. Leave the Value field the way it is, but change the Label field to the new column you created.

Now the dropdown will show the friendly label, but use the real value behind the scenes!

Comment: Thank you Steven for the insights, I'll have a look into it